# How can I animate a progress bar for the loading of a page?

Tags: progress

I'm not experienced with javascript, so I was wondering if anyone knew a script that would work with my progressbar.

I have it set up like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<style>
progress {
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
color: #1990c8;
appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-o-appearance: none;
}
progress::-moz-progress-bar { 
background: #1990c8;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
background: #1990c8;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
background: #e1e1e1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<progress id="progressbar" value="50" max="100"></progress>
</body>
</html>
```

As the page is loading I want the value of the progress bar to go from 0 to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Read head first for jquery you can learn lot,Have look on http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#default

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Also TwitterBootstrap provide a nice progress bar, based on CSS3 animation (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress).

You can animate the bar simply changing its width: in this simple fiddle, I use jQuery to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/marcogualtieri/qG2Kr/

HTML:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function fake_elaboration(step) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    step++;
    $(".progress-bar").width(step + "%");
    if (step != 100) {
        fake_elaboration(step);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            // action to perform when bar is completed
        }, 300);
    }
  }, 100); 
}
```

As you can see, wait is simulated with a recursive function with an inner timeout.
You just have to call this function when page is loaded, passing -1 as initial step.

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript can do what you want, its creating youtube style, top progress bar loading.

http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/